# Вывод строк по id

Tags: php, mysql

Только начал учить php(сразу на практике). Прошу вашей помощи.
Мне нужно вывести Название новости, которое равно id новости. Текст новости, который равен id новости. И нужно вывести дату новости, которая равна id новости. Но, к сожалению, не могу понять как это сделать. Помогите, пожалуйста, у меня не хватает знаний.

```
<?php
    // Новости
    $get_rows_news = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM news");
    $rows_news = mysqli_num_rows($get_rows_news);

    $get_date_news = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'date' FROM news");
    $get_text_news = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'text' FROM news");
    $get_name_news = $mysqli->query("SELECT 'name' FROM news");

    for($i=0; $i < $rows_news ; ++$i){
?>

<div class="smart-container">
    <div class="titlenews">
        <?php echo "Название новости" ?>
        <span class="newsdate">
            <?php echo "Дата новости"; ?>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="textnews">
        <p>Текст новости</p>
    </div>
</div>

<?php 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Тогда начните с изучения sql. он может гораздо больше, чем получать одну колонку из всей таблицы. старайтесь делать все за минимум запросов к БД (SQL вообще позволяет получить любые данные, как бы сложны они ни были и в скольких бы таблицах не располагались, за один запрос). В вашем случае вам надо что то вроде `select id, date, text, name from news where id=?`, привязать с помощью http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php нужное значение id и выполнить запрос. он вам вернет сразу все требуемые поля из одной единственной записи с указанным id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE 1");
//если нужна новость с идентификатором 10, то раскомментировать следующую строку, а предыдущую убрать
// $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='10'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $data["name"];
        $date = $data["date"];
        $text = $data["text"];
?>
        <div class="smart-container">
            <div class="titlenews">
                <?php echo $name; ?>
                <span class="newsdate">
                    <?php echo $date; ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="textnews">
                <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Бд подключил, вывод пустой(
Даже цикл не выполнился

Comment: Спасибо, вы помогли. 
Только у меня не mysql, а mysqli 
Вчера 4 часа из-за этого просидел =\

Comment: Да, не обратил внимания, что mysqli. Не думаю, что что-то будет сильно отличаться.